# how to merge two video using FFMPEG?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

```
String Tmp1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "scary.mp4";
inputCode = new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(getApplicationContext()),
                "-i", Tmp1, "-i", VideoPath, "-filter_complex",
                "[0:v][1:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.8[v_out]", "-map", "[v_out]", "-map", "0:a", "-strict", "-2", VideoPath};
```

inputCode is execute string.

Comment: what is wrong with the piece of code you provided?

Comment: cross check driectory name where your output should be save

Comment: may ffmpeg not found directory

Comment: and you passs VideoPath for both input and output that is not allowed

Comment: i think there is some problem in command due to  which  output file is not generated. can you check  this command? @Vinesh Chauhan

Comment: let me check first but i m sure if command is wrong ffmpeg definetly throuw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

success fully  marge a File using this command

```
inputCode = new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(getApplicationContext()),"-y","-i",InputPath1, "-i",InputPath2,"-strict","experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1", "-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","-s","480x640","-r","30","-vcodec","mpeg4","-b","2097k",OutPutPath};
```

thank you..

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg command should be

```
   String Tmp1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "scary.mp4";
    inputCode = new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(getApplicationContext()),
                    "-i", Tmp1, "-i", VideoPath, "-filter_complex",
                    "[0:v][1:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.8[v_out]", "-map", "[v_out]", "-map", "0:a", "-strict", "-2", "/sdcard/OutPutVideo.mp4"};
```

input and output file not to be same

Comment: W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/user/0/photo.edit.scaryvideomaker/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/scary.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/ThugsLifeVideoMaker/videofiles/TL1537877161938.mp4, -filter_complex, [0:v][1:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.8[v_out], -map, [v_out], -map, 0:a, -strict, -2, /sdcard/OutPutVideo.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: have you intialize ffmpeg

Comment: inputCode = new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(getApplicationContext()),"-y","-i",InputPath1,
                    "-i",InputPath2,"-strict","experimental",
                    "-filter_complex",
                    "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
                    "-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","-s","480x640","-r","30","-vcodec","mpeg4","-b","2097k",OutPutPath};